# Evaluate a determinant

Tags: linear-algebra

> Evaluate the determinant
>   $$
> D_{n+1}=\begin{pmatrix}
> a_1^n & a_1^{n-1}b_1 & \cdots & a_1b_1^{n-1} & b_1^n\\
> a_2^n & a_2^{n-1}b_2 & \cdots & a_2b_1^{n-1} & b_1^n\\
> \vdots& \vdots&&\vdots&\vdots\\
> a_{n+1}^n & a_{n+1}^{n-1}b_{n+1} & \cdots & a_{n+1}b_{n+1}^{n-1} & b_{n+1}^n
> \end{pmatrix}
> $$

What I can find is $(a_1-b_1)(a_1^{n}+a_1^{n-1}b_1+\cdots+a_1b_1^{n-1}+b_1^n)=a_1^{n+1}-b_1^{n+1}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a variant of the Vandermonde determinant. One gets
$$\det D_{n+1}=(b_1\cdots b_{n+1})^n
\begin{vmatrix}
c_1^n&c_1^{n-1}&\cdots&c_1&1\\
c_2^n&c_2^{n-1}&\cdots&c_2&1\\
\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots&\vdots\\
c_{n+1}^n&c_{n+1}^{n-1}&\cdots&c_{n+1}&1
\end{vmatrix}$$
where each $c_i=a_i/b$. Using the formula for the Vandermonde determinant
we soon get to
$$\det D_{n+1}=\prod_{1\le i<j\le n+1}(a_ib_j-a_jb_i).$$